# RCU.bat file not opening on virtual machine

Tags: debugging, batch-file

I have installed a Windows 2008 Server on my VM. I am trying to run a `.bat` file (on my VM).  This `.bat` file is stored on my local Windows 7 PC, and I'm using shared folders to access it.

The `.bat` file does not work on my virtual machine. There is no error shown. The command prompt window pops up and then goes away..

However this file works fine on my PC. What could be the reason for the file to run on one system and not run on the other?

How can I run this `.bat` using the command prompt of my virtual machine? To check if any error log shows up? What could be done? Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: Most likely that batch file specifically use file/folder that's only present in real PC. i.e.: paths no longer valid

Comment: Put a `pause` at the end of the batch file and see if any errors appear in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Are you double-clicking on the `.bat` file through windows explorer? Open the command prompt, then `cd` to where you have the file and just run it.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd` cannot use UNC paths as the current path. I'm guessing your shared folders use a network share in the guest machine. Map that share to a drive letter and try again.